# An order statistics problem with some interesting geometry

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions

Let $a_n$ be a given sequence of positive numbers, and $X_n$ a sequence of independent random variables with each $X_n$ uniformly distributed on $[0, a_n]$.

**Question:** Let $N \geq 2$ be an arbitrary integer. What is

$$\mathbb P(X_N > X_{N-1} > \dots > X_1)$$

for the following choices of $a_n$?

i) Arithmetic progression: $a_n = n$.

ii) Geometric progression: $a_n = 2^n$.

iii) Square numbers: $a_n = n^2$.

**Comments:**

The problem seems to boil down to computing the (normalized) volume of some complicated $N$-dimensional shapes. For example, in the simplest case of a constant sequence $a_n = 1$, the probability is the volume of the standard $N$-simplex, $\frac{1}{N!}$.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but a guess that may help someone... Based on computing the first few values $P_N:=\mathbb{P}(X_N>X_{N-1}>\cdots>X_1)$ it is not too difficult to guess the formulas
$$P_N = \frac{(N+1)^{N-1}}{(N!)^2}$$
for $a_n=n$ and the generating function
$$\sum_{N=0}^\infty P_N x^N = \frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\, 2^{-k(k-1)/2} x^k}$$
for $a_n = 2^n$.

Comment: Maybe, you can prove the general formula by induction ?

Comment: @G.Melfi Induction is not likely to work, since considering the inductive hypothesis on the previous $N-1$ terms tells you the volume of the projection of the $N$ dimensional shape onto the $N-1$ plane spanned by the first few coordinates. Which unfortunately says nothing about the volume of the original shape. I do have an alternative combinatorial description though… will post it up when I have time.

Comment: @Timothy Budd The formula I have agrees with yours for $N = 2, 3$. It is written as a combinatorial sum instead of explicitly.

Comment: In fact I’ve just checked it up to $N = 13$.

Comment: See G. P. Steck,, https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-42/issue-1/Rectangle-Probabilities-for-Uniform-Order-statistics-and-the-Probability-That/10.1214/aoms/1177693490.full. For more recent work, see my paper with Jim Pitman at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-002-2776-6 and the references therein.

Comment: @RichardStanley Thanks for the references! Unfortunately the first link doesn't seem to be working, is there another source?

Comment: @NateRiver This link works for me. The full reference is Rectangle Probabilities for Uniform Order statistics and the Probability That the Empirical Distribution Function Lies Between Two Distribution Functions,G. P. Steck, *Ann. Math. Statist.* 42(1): 1-11 (February, 1971).