# A combinatorial identity involving increasing functions from $\{1, \dots, n\}$ to itself

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis

This is related to the post [An order statistics problem with some interesting geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457249/an-order-statistics-problem-with-some-interesting-geometry). The following identity arose in the context of the problem.

Fix an integer $N \geq 2$. Let $\mathcal S_N^+$ denote the set of nonstrictly increasing functions from $\{1, \dots, N\}$ to itself with $f(n) \leq n$ for all $n \in \{1, \dots, N\}$. Then it would appear that we have

$$ \sum_{f \in S_N^+} \prod_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{|f^{-1} (n)|!} = \frac{(N+1)^{N-1}}{N!}$$

where by convention we take $0! = 1$.

After dividing both sides by $N!$, the left hand side is an expression for the probability in question that myself and a friend managed to prove rigorously, while the right hand side was guessed by Timothy Budd to be the expression for the same probability. Both sides have been numerically verified to agree with the probability in question up to $N = 13$.

**Question:** Can we prove this identity is true?

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you, looking forward to the answer.

Comment: I don't think $\text{“} 0!=1 \text{”}$ is merely a convention. $\qquad$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that $N!/\prod_{n=1}^N |f^{-1}(n)|!$ is just the number of
rearrangements of the sequence $(f(1),\dots,f(N))$. Thus $N!$ time the
left-hand side of your formula is the number of sequences
$(a_1,\dots,a_N)$ of positive integers whose increasing rearrangement
$b_1\leq b_2\leq \cdots\leq b_N$ satisfies $b_i\leq i$. Such sequences
are known as *parking functions* of length $N$. There is a huge
literature on them, including many proofs that the number of them is
$(N+1)^{N-1}$. For a survey see C. Yan,
[https://people.tamu.edu/~huafei-yan//Files/Yan-Final-Own-Copy.pdf](https://people.tamu.edu/%7Ehuafei-yan//Files/Yan-Final-Own-Copy.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have only a cursory knowledge of combinatorics so it appears I have asked something very well known.

Comment: @NateRiver Yes; however, a lot of results in this area are surprisingly recent. It is an unexpectedly rich topic.